# Should I send a mail to query the process of my manuscript since it is in the "Awaiting EIC Decision" status for two weeks?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

One of my manuscript was submitted to a journal in one year and four months ago, and after two rounds of reviews, its status was changed to "Awaiting EIC Decision" two weeks ago. As far as I know, the "Awaiting EIC Decision" status is the final time when the chief editor to decide whether to accept or reject the paper, but it seems the editors handled with my manuscript a little slow. Is there a chance the CE(Chief Editor) overlooked the status change of my manuscript? and should I send a requesting e-mail to speed up the process?

I am not sure my e-mail will affect the final decision of my manuscript, and whom should I sent the e-mail to, the AE or the CE? since the manuscript is in the "Awaiting EIC Decision" status.

Comment: You waited one year and four months. Now _its status was changed to "Awaiting EIC Decision" two weeks ago_. What's the reason you cannot wait another two weeks or so before you send the query mail?

Comment: @scaaahu I didn't even expect so long for my manuscript and I have sent several e-mails to the AE during the process. If not I think I may wait even longer.

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering the same situation and I fully understand that how it feels when it comes to a final decision.

1. There must be many papers awaiting EiC's decision. The request to jump to the queue is a bit impolite.
2. I think it has small chances that the requesting email would affect the final decision because I think AE already has a decision or recommendation. But it would have a negative effect for your next submissions;
3. I would suggest to send email to EiC directly after 4 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be too precious about this. That is to say, if you feel like emailing the journal about clarifying the status of your publication, please do so. As long as you do it in a professional manner, space your requests appropriately over time and are reasonable about timelines, then there shouldn't be a reason for journal staff to react negatively about this. This is the situation in the Journal I help manage.

If you choose to write to the journal, I would suggest that you write first to the associate editor who's handling your manuscript. Writing to the Editor-in-Chief is tricky because you close off your final avenue of reply right away. You need to be able to escalate things, and this can't happen if you shoot an email to the Editor-in-Chief. We suggest that our authors contact the associate editor in the first instance, escalate things to the managing editor and only then write to the Editor-in-Chief.

Writing to the associate editors may provide them with the added evidence they need to poke the Editor-in-Chief into action. During staff meetings when manuscripts are discussed, it is common for us to bring to the attention of the people around the table delays such as these.

Despite @Hui's misgivings, writing to journal staff does not produce a negative effect on your present or subsequent submissions. I'm not aware of a single journal belonging to the [ICMJE](http://www.icmje.org/) so petty as to have this policy (written or unwritten). Certainly, make sure you that you are professional about your contact.

Good luck to you.